# What is corrupting my layer file?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, layers, attribute-joins, xy

I'm trying to save layer files from a colleague's mxd. As usual I right clicked on the layer and saved as layer file. Simple - but no - the layer files can't be opened. I get this message

> "Adding the selected layer file failed. Possible reasons include that
>   it may have been created using a newer version of ArcGIS and can't be
>   opened in the version you are using"

Its not a different version of ArcGIS - I've been using 10.2.2 the whole time. I've had a look at the layers to find anything unusual about them. They are slightly unusual in that is it a table stored in a mdb joined to a point feature class in the same .mdb with XY events displayed. I've tried with other tables and with the same tables in a .gdb and I have the same problem. Joining the FC to the table works fine, but there is a one to many relationship so not all of the rows from the table are displayed.

Is this a limitation that I can't get round or does anyone know of a solution? Perhaps there's something else that's causing the problem that I haven't thought of.

Comment: So are you trying to create a .lyr file from an XY event layer? Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: If you are in fact trying to create a .lyr file from an XY even layer as @Dan_h_b asks, you probably won't and shouldn't be able to do that. You would likely have to export the event layer to a shapefile/feature calss first.  The XY event layer is not permanently storing the actual data in any database, so they're no really data source for a layer file to point to (other than the original MXD/script the event layer was created in).  Run the feature class to feature class gp tool on the event layer, then save layer file for that.

Comment: The problem is that its an access database that colleagues of mine are continually updating. If I created an export it would lose its connection to the data.
I tried saving an XY event layer with out a join and that seemed to work fine.

Comment: Would it be a practical solution creating a *view* to the table in this DB?